# docker how to assign memory associated with cpu

Tags: docker, memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

I want to run N docker containers on a given physical host.  I want to limit each container to a subset of total resources (RAM and cpu).

In doing this, I want to take the machine architecture into account.  I have 128 gigs of ram.  64 gigs are more closely associated with half of the cpu's and the other 64 gigs are more closely associated with the other half of cpu's.

My question is, how do I specify which exact cpu's and which exact memory segments to give to the docker container.  I will get best performance if the communication between cpu and RAM has the lowest latency possible.

I have looked at the documentation and I don't see the answer.  Am I missing it?  Is there some other documentation or perhaps plugin to docker that will make this possible?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as all the cpu's you assign to the docker container are associated with the same processor, the operating system should give preference to neuma memory associated with that processor (this is not a guarantee, but should work if memory isn't constrained).